# SQL Unique rows query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

I got the following entries:

```
Col_A  | Col_B  | Col_C
Foo    | Bar    | 1
Foo    | Blub   | 1
Foo    | Bar    | 1
Foo    | Blub   | 2
Foo    | Blub   | 2
Foo    | Bar    | 3
Foo    | Bar    | 3
Foo    | Bar    | 3
Foo    | Blub   | 4
Foo    | Bar    | 5
Foo    | Blub   | 5
```

I'm search for all Col_C values where in Col_B only contain Blub. Which mean I want to see

```
Col_A  | Col_B  | Col_C
Foo    | Blub   | 2
Foo    | Blub   | 4
```

A distinct row where there is no entry Bla in Col_B

currently I also receive

```
Foo    | Blub   | 1
Foo    | Blub   | 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM your_table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM your_table t2
     WHERE t2.col_b <> 'Blub'
     AND t1.col_a = t2.col_a
     AND t1.col_c = t2.col_c)
AND t1.col_b = 'Blub'
```

See the [**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7c5b/2/0)